# queries in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

hello i have tried the foollowing code and it is showing only assignment,call increment and new object expression can be uesd as a statement

```
var res = from results in db.JobSearchAgents
where results.SiteID == 110 && results.UserID == sess
select new Agentlist
{
    JobSearchAgentID = results.JobSearchAgentID.ToString(),
    EmailAddress = results.EmailAddress,
    Keywords = results.Keywords,
    Country = results.Country,
    zipcode =  results.ZipCode,
    miles = results.Miles.ToString(),
    IsActive=results.IsActive.ToString()

};
string country= (new  ObservableCollection<Agentlist>(res))[0].Country);
```

please give me the soluttion

Comment: why are you creating an observable collection taking first item and then throwing it away?

Comment: so how can i do this if i have to store res.country value in another string variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect multiple results from the query try this:

```
// Calling ToList will force query execution.
List<Agentlist> result = res.ToList<Agentlist>();

// Calling First will take the first item in the collection.
// If there are more than one item it will NOT throw 
// an exception (calling Single() will).
Agentlist agent = result.First<Agentlist>();

string country = agent.Country;
```

If you need only the first result of the query you can try calling `First()` right away:

```
Agentlist agent = res.First<Agentlist>();
```